# How I get de viewId on activity with 4 imageview?

Tags: android

I'd like to reduce the code below to a function that gets `viewId` and shows it using the `Toast` command. Then method `setOnclick` to one, not repeat it for `aluno` and `notas`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_principal);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mtela);

    sala = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sala);
    professor = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.professor);
    aluno = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.aluno);
    notas = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.notas);

    sala.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sala"+sala.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    professor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sala"+professor.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST OPTION**
You can use the attribute onClick in your ImageView tag, inside of the attribute, tap alt+enter and create your method for each ImageView

**SECOND OPTION**
You can use the extends `View.OnClickListener` in this class, and implement the method `onClick`. After this, you code and switch-case to get the id of the ImageViews

Answer (score 0):

First create your onClick function in the main activity:

```
   public void onClick(View view){

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId()) + view.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

I am using the "getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId())" to get the NAME of the ID and "view.getId()" to get the ID number as you wanted.

Then add that function to be the listener for each image view in your XML

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:-

Implement onClickListener to activity and override onClick().

Set all of the objects like sala.setOnClickListener(this).

In that display toast after check the clicked view by checking it via clicked object's id.
view.getId()==R.id.sala....if true display toast.

Follow the same step for every object which is to be clicked.